# login into an app from adb shell using am start commands

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, adb

If I'm testing an app, using am start commands in an android/adb shell.
And the app requires a user to log in before proceeding to the main content.
How can I log in the app from the android command line using am start commands.

My lack of understanding is how to access those form fields from the shell/am start commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alex's answer is good, I gave it an up. To be more specific. Here is some of my code After your am start command.

```
adb shell input keyevent 20  # or 61 for TAB, you might need to do more than once
adb shell input text "myusername"
adb shell input keyevent 66      #or 61 for TAB
adb shell input text "mypassword"
adb shell input keyevent 66    # or 61 to tab to the login button then add a 66
```

My problem is that I had to bring the screen to focus first to make this code work. I had to touch the screen once, then the code will be fine. Otherwise it works sometimes, but sometimes it does not work.

I don't know what code can do the "bring to focus" function. Low level touch event will work, but it is different for different android versions, so I don't want to use it.

Comment: to take care of the focus issue you could either send touch event (starting with ICS there is no need for "low level" stuff, just use `input tap`) or you could start the app with `am start -S <intent>` to force-close the previous instance if any - in this case the new instance is going to have focus (in my experience).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried "adb shell input tap 100 100" on a 4.0.4 AOKP rom but it is an unknown command. Also I need solution for any android version so this will satisfy anyway. I also tried am start -S, it will stop prevous instance but still does not bring in focus. The search continues...

Comment: +1 for you..... would you know `keyevent <key code number ?>` all the info about which code number does what? any help?

Comment: all the key code are listed at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_0                 The value of the constants are the key code.

Answer (score 2):

use `input` command

```
usage: input ...
   input text <string>
   input keyevent <key code number or name>
   input tap <x> <y>
   input swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2>
```

use `input keyevent`with DPAD and/or TAB key codes to locate the field, then `input text` to fill it, then `input keyevent` with ENTER or DPAD_CENTER to submit